# How to extract some specific strings from a list and store them in variables in beautifulsoup?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I would like to extract specific strings on a list of multiple items containing multiple tags (and strings). And store them into variables.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/DFletcher1990/')
r.html.render(sleep=5)

soup=BeautifulSoup(r.html.html,'html.parser')

user_socio_table=soup.find_all('div', class_='discussion-stat')
print(user_socio_table)
```

Here is the supposed output of `print(user_socio_table)`:

```
[<div class="discussion-stat">
            4<span class="discussion-light"> questions</span>
</div>, <div class="discussion-stat">
            444<span class="discussion-light"> votes</span>
</div>, <div class="discussion-stat">
            718<span class="discussion-light"> answers</span>
</div>, <div class="discussion-stat">
            15<span class="discussion-light"> flags raised</span>
</div>, <div class="discussion-stat">
            10<span class="discussion-light"> project help requests</span>
</div>, <div class="discussion-stat">
            38<span class="discussion-light"> project help replies</span>
</div>, <div class="discussion-stat">
            208<span class="discussion-light"> comments</span>
</div>, <div class="discussion-stat">
            11<span class="discussion-light"> tips and thanks</span>
</div>]
```

- I would like to store `4` into a variable called `questions`,
- I would like to store `444` into a variable called `votes`,
- I would like to store `718` into a variable called `answers`,
- I would like to store `15` into a variable called `flags`,
- I would like to store `10` into a variable called `help_requests`,
- I would like to store `38` into a variable called `help_replies`,
- I would like to store `208` into a variable called `comments`,
- I would like to store `11` into a variable called `tips_thanks`.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get values by one by and add it in json array

```
data = {}
for gettext in user_socio_table:
   category = gettext.find('span')
   category_text = category.text.strip()  ## get text in span
   number = category.previousSibling.strip() ## get value before span tag
   data[category_text] = number ## add it


print(data)
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
{'questions': '4', 'votes': '444', 'answers': '718', 'flags raised': '15', 'project help requests': '10', 'project help replies': '38', 'comments': '208', 'tips and thanks': '11'}
```

You can get value with spesific one

```
print(data['questions'])
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
4
```